# Splitting Text information in a dataframe into single words and detect if they are part of a dictionary R

Tags: r, dataframe, nlp

I am trying write a script to detect if one word of an undefined amount of words is part of a dictionary.

To make this problem a bit more understandable, I have the following data:

```
Items | Descriptions    | 
-------------------------
Item1 | poster           
Item2 | used cd music etc
Item3 | hckd herbal ingds.
Item4 | 823942 blc
```

So what I want to do know, is to check the column descriptions if any of those single words is part of a dictionary or self created vector of strings.
So the result should look something like:

```
Items | Descriptions       | inDictionary
--------------------------------------------------
Item1 | poster             | TRUE
Item2 | used cd music etc  | TRUE
Item3 | hckd herbal ingds. | TRUE
Item4 | 823942 blc         | FALSE
```

For this example I just assume a english dictionary. In this specific case its sufficient if only one word is part of a dictionary.

I already tried this with the qdapDictionaries library and tokenizers to tokenize the contents of the dataframe cells but I fail to get the check right for cells where I have more than one word.

Help is much appreciated,

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I don't know which dictionary you are working with, here's a description of how **in principle** you can go about this task:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Descriptions = c("cyber"," &%@","aah ingds.", "823942 blc"))
```

Let's say you work with the `GradyAugmented` dictionary from the `library(qdapDictionaries)`, you could paste the words in the dictionary together separating them by the regex alternation marker `|`and use `grepl`, which returns TRUE or FALSE, to check whether the dictionary words are contained in any of the `df$Description` strings:

```
df$inDict <- grepl(paste0("\\b(", paste(GradyAugmented[1:100], collapse = "|"), ")\\b"), df$Descriptions)
```

Result:

```
df
  Descriptions inDict
1        cyber   TRUE   
2          &%@  FALSE   
3   aah ingds.   TRUE
4   823942 blc  FALSE
```

The dictionary may be very large and you may run into memory problems. In that case you can take a different route, via `%in%`:

```
df$inDict <- lapply(strsplit(df$Descriptions, " "), function(x) x %in% GradyAugmented)
```

Here the rows are lists:

```
df$inDict <- lapply(strsplit(df$Descriptions, " "), function(x) x %in% GradyAugmented)
df
  Descriptions       inDict
1        cyber         TRUE
2          &%@        FALSE
3   aah ingds.  TRUE, FALSE
4   823942 blc FALSE, FALSE
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be exactly the process I was looking for! As soon as i get back i test it!
Thank you very much!

Comment: I was now able to try it. 
When i use the GradyAugmented out of the qdapDictionaries library, I get the following error:  

  
**Error in grepl(paste0("\\b(", dict, "\\b)", collapse = "|"), df$description) : 
  invalid regular expression 'Out of memory'**

Comment: This is a memory problem (the dictionary is too long). If you cut it it into smaller chunks, the code works. See edited answer.

Comment: Hi I've added another solution which should work. Try it out and let me know what you think.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your thoughts, That was my initial idea.
Problem with this solution, as soon as I have a sentence or more than one word, it will generate a FALSE, I think this comes from that %in% doesnt check word by word but takes the whole cell as a string, in your data for example : aah ingds. will be interpreted as "aah ingds." instead of separate strings "aah" and  "ingds." Thats why I then tried to tokenize the descriptions and check token by token, but that didnt work either

Comment: I started it now, as its a pretty big dataframe, I let you know as soon as its done

Comment: Okay it did its job and it actually worked! Thank you so much! In the next step I will generate an extra column where I sum up the logicals so that I know when its >0 I have a word from the dictionary or not, Thank you again for the help!

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it worked. Please consider accepting the answer.